# Excluding a duplicate package in gradle

Tags: gradle, javafx, java-19

I have a gradle build that uses javafx, log4j from maven and jOpenDocument-1.5 from a jar in a local flatDir (folder).  When I build under JDK19 I get the following errors

```
error: the unnamed module reads package org.w3c.dom from both jOpenDocument and java.xml
error: module javafx.graphicsEmpty reads package org.w3c.dom from both jOpenDocument and java.xml
error: module javafx.baseEmpty reads package org.w3c.dom from both jOpenDocument and java.xml
error: module org.apache.logging.log4j.core reads package org.w3c.dom from both jOpenDocument and java.xml
error: module javafx.controlsEmpty reads package org.w3c.dom from both jOpenDocument and java.xml
error: module jOpenDocument reads package org.w3c.dom from both java.xml and jOpenDocument
```

Gradle provides a collection of mechanisms that should allow me to exclude the org.w3c.com package from the build.  Gradle wants me to specify a "group" and/or a "module", but the error messages specify a "java package" but not the group and module names.

I would like the build to use the org.w3c.dom package from java.xml and exclude the org.w3c.dom package from jOpenDocument.  I chose the java.xml variant of the package because the jOpenDocument variant has just *org.w3c.dom.UserDataHandler.class* so removing it should make it less likely to have side-effects in other dependencies.

The Gradle build scans did not go down to a package level analysis.  It doesn't really tell me anything I can act on.  That may be more my ignorance.

The following snippet from my build.gradle file is what I have now.  It doesn't work probably because *org.w3c.dom* is a **package** and not a gradle/maven **module**.

```
dependencies {
    testImplementation 'org.testng:testng:7.4.0'

    implementation 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.14.1'
    implementation 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.14.1'

    implementation ('libs:jOpenDocument-1.5') {
        exclude module: 'org.w3c.dom'
    }

}
```

1. How should I amend the build.gradle file to resolve this duplicate dependency?
2. What is a Gradle build dependency module if its not a package?

Comment: I'm not sure this is something Gradle can solve, at least not just by trying to exclude certain dependencies. Note that the error is coming from Java, not Gradle. The "modules" mentioned in the error are related to the [_Java Platform Module System_ (JPMS) modules](https://www.oracle.com/corporate/features/understanding-java-9-modules.html), added in Java 9. That is a different concept from Gradle's "module".

Comment: What you can maybe try to do is manually remove the `/org/w3c/dom/UserDataHandler.class` file from the JAR file (note JAR files are just ZIP files). Since you apparently had to download the JAR manually and use a local flat directory repository, this should be easier to do; just edit the file and be done with it. Whether or not that works depends on why _jOpenDocument_ felt the need to have its own version of that class in the first place.

Comment: I think I'll have a go at removing the org.w3c.dom package.  If it works I'll report back.  How hard can it be? ...

Comment: “How hard can it be?” -> [jar msn page](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/specs/man/jar.html) should be your friend in the respect.  Run `jar -x` to extract the content, delete the unwanted files, then run `jar-c` to recreate the fixed jar.

Comment: Your other option may be to make your app non-modular if it isn’t already (don’t include a module-info and follow instructions at openjfx.up for non-modular projects).  That is not guaranteed to work, because the jOpenDocument is badly packaged, but it might work.

Comment: Removing the org.w3c.dom package appears to have worked. I need to look into the next build problem to make sure I haven't created a problem as a consequence. The problem error message seems unrelated, so I'm hopeful.

Comment: Regarding making the application non-modular (in the JDK9 - JDK21 sense of the word). I thought that a recent JDK added a restriction on duplicate packages whether the program was modular or not. Sadly, I cannot recall where I read about this or in which JDK it was introduced - so I may be mistaken. I have a feeling it was 11 or 14.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed the **/org/w3c/dom/UserDataHandler.class** file and its parent folder at **org/w3c/dom** from the JAR file (JAR files being ZIP files) manually. *(Thank you [@Slaw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6395627/slaw))*

... job done.  Note that I have yet to test whether there are any functional side-effects.

The latest version (jOpenDocument-1.5.jar) is not on Maven. So, I could edit the JAR manually in my local flat directory repository. I used ark to do the deleting.  That may change - I see a request has been made.  I would prefer to use officially published versions from Maven because they more maintainable over the long term.  So, towards the end of development, I will have a go at enhancing my **build.gradle** file to perform this edit programmatically, most likely using **jar** commands, *as suggested by [@jewelsea](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1155209/jewelsea),*

Two closing thoughts if I may.

1. I am trying out Test Driven Development for the first time.  TDD probably brought this problem forward, which I count as a good thing.  The benefit being I do not have any rework to do; so +1 for TDD.
2. With deleting a class from a jar being so straightforward, I cannot help but feel there should be a conventional way to specify excluding a specific class or package in the build configuration.  If it exists, it will be documented somewhere in the Gradle or Gradle plug-in manuals; and that will require an archaeological dig, time and a spare brain cell.

Comment: Good news: My experience is that this solution is behaving well in tests.